# SYSPART hidden folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

We had a user with a Lenovo G-series laptop getting a STOP error on boot. We reinstalled Windows 7 Home Premium using non-OEM media and restored the user's files from backup. We are now seeing a hidden folder in the root of the C:\ drive called SYSPART which appears to contain a copy of the contents of the C:\ drive - so while the user has 160 GB of files, the drive is using 320 GB because of this folder.

What is it, and is it safe to delete?

Comment: Evidently you did not do a clean re-install, when in doubt back it up on an external drive until you know its safe to delete it. Usually when you do an upgrade install it will put the contents of the old C: into a folder called "windows.old" not sure what install disc you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Lenovo G series laptop also. The SYSPART folder contains all of the C: drive data. Lenovo uses a strange configuration for their drives.

I backed-up all the data from the SYSPART folder, then formatted the drive. Afterwards, I installed Windows 8 clean. I then copied the data that I needed from the SYSPART folder back to the C: drive.

If you are confident that you have all the required data from SYSPART (e.g., C:\SYSPART\Users\UserName\Documents), then you can delete that folder. You will be prompted several times to confirm the deletion of System and Hidden folders.